# Django model: OperationalError: no such column: home_atliktas_darbas.bendrija_id, help fix, Django version 3.2

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a model that is related to other one, meaning the model I am trying to create can't exist if the model its related to does not exist.
now I am new to django (just a few months), but I have created models with the same concept and had no issues before, this is the first time this has happened and I have no idea what could be the cause

this is the model its related to

```
class Bendrija(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bendrijos'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is the model I want to create

```
class Atliktas_Darbas(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Atlikti Darbai'

    bendrija = models.ForeignKey(Bendrija, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="atliktas_darbas")
    pavadinimas = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    aprasymas = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    preliminari_kaina = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    galutine_kaina = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    atlikti_iki = models.DateField()
    darbas_atlikas = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    pastabos = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pavadinimas
```

first I thought I forgot to add "bendrija' (the model field) to list_display in admin.py and I was correct thinking that fixed it I thought I was done, but I was wrong, after that I tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing worked

Comment: Have you run makemigrations and migration command?

Comment: ya I did, luckily my database was empty to begin with so I just deleted it and ran those migrations again and its fixed now, but still a weird bug I was wondering how to fix incase I couldn't just delete my database and start over